# Should we close one of these questions about whether $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ as a duplicate of the other?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156473/264) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57890/264) are both asking about $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$, though the first one is specifically asking about interpreting it in the context of probability. Should one of these questions be closed as a duplicate? Or, should someone post an all-encompassing question (and answer) about this topic, so that others can be closed as a duplicate of it? If so, who's up for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These $\frac{1}{\infty}$ questions are annoying. Luckily, they are not terribly frequent, and the OP *has* found a variant.  My inclination is to interpret "duplicate" quite narrowly, and not close.

Comment: I agree—I think the particular focus on probability in the first of the two links makes it a distinct enough question.